# Java how to register a class instance so that any class can find

Tags: java, middleware, stub

Suppose I have a Java class like this:

```
public class FibSolver{
    int fib(int n){
        //returns n-th term of fibonacci sequence
    }
}
```

I want to register an instance of this class (called FibService), just like RMI service does when registering .stub files, so that other classes that need this service can call it doing something like this:

```
FibSolver f = (FibSolver) FindMyService("FibService");
int fib5 = f.fib(5);
```

But I'm doing this from the beginning and don't want to use RMI.

It is also possible to have multiple different classes working as public services, so I'd rather have something like a .stub file than static instances of each class.

How can I do this registering/retrieving instances of services thing?

Comment: You could put the class in a Jar file on the class-path.  You could use a custom class loader that loads class files that you make.  If the client is using a special loader like JNDI or a factory, you could register with that particular service.  But due to security concerns there's no general purpose "make other classes load from here."  That's all in cooperation with the operator and the classes in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating each "service" as a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).
I would create an interface of IMyService.
The interface will have one function getService.
Each service will have its C'Tor as private and implement the getService method to provide the single instance of itself.

Then register all of these services on a global map with its string name.
The map could be a global static member which of course can access the static singlton getters of each service.

Makes sense?

Comment: sure it makes sense, but as I said, *I'd rather have something like a .stub file than static instances of each class*, if this is my only choice, I'll do it the way you suggested, but I'm looking for something like the .stub workflow

Comment: You mean that you want to create the class object by name? If so I guess you could do that using reflection. Are you familiar with it?

Comment: yes, and I think I'll give up the .stub solution and go for yours

Answer (score 1):

Singleton is the way for doing this. A simple implementation will be like this:

```
public class FibSolver {
   private static FibSolver instance;

   public static FibSolver getInstance() {
      if (instance == null) {
         instance = new FibSolver();
      }
      return instance;
   }

   private FibSolver() {
   }

   int fib(int n){
      //returns n-th term of fibonacci sequence
   }
}
```

You get the instance by calling:

```
FibSolver f = FibSolver.getInstance();
```

An improved version can use a static HashMap to assign a String for different instances and maybe different solvers.